# Public Access level to the pages in Joomla1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

I am working on Joomla 1.5 . i have a link to an article whose access level is set to Public but still its asking for login for that page since we have set tat to some access level previously..

Please give some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts are:

- If there's a menu item pointing to the article, make sure that the menu item doesn't have any access restrictions.
- You could also try [clearing Joomla's cache.](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/1986/236/)